# Change all done replacements to something else

Tags: git, diff

While rewriting a legacy application, I did some mass replacing of `foo` by `bar` intermixed with many manual changes. Some replacements had to be undone manually and there were already many other `bar`s in the original code.

Now, I see that each `foo` replaced by `bar` should actually be `baz`.

An example:

- old file:
  `a staying "foo" and a replaced "foo" and a kept "bar"`
- new file
  `a staying "foo" and a replaced "bar" and a kept "bar"`
- wanted
  `a staying "foo" and a replaced "baz" and a kept "bar"`

The wanted action is simple: Fix every replacement of `foo` by `bar` to `baz`. I wonder if there's a simple way using `git` or any Linux tools.

## Reformulation

Maybe this single sentence formulation is clearer:

*Given two versions of a file, put `baz` in every place where the old version contains `foo` and the new version contains `bar`.*

## More details

There were actually three *whole words* replacements by words of *differing lengths* like

```
perl -pe 's/\babc\b/pqrs/gi; s/\bdefg\b/uvw/gi; s/\bhi\b/xyz/g'
```

Comment: You just want to change the commit message, and not the actual files?

Comment: @ObsidianAge No, I want to change the files. And there's no single commit and I actually don't care about the history... it was a big chaos till I got a compiling version. Let's say, I made a wrong mass replacement and I need to fix it, while keeping all manual changes.

Comment: To downvoters: Is there something unclear about the question?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471183/linux-command-line-global-search-and-replace

Comment: @dommmm That's what I did: `perl -pi -e 's!foo!bar!g`. That's what I should've done: `perl -pi -e 's!foo!baz!g`. In between, I did many manual changes. I can't do simply `perl -pi -e 's!bar!baz!g` now, as not every occurrence should be replaced.

Comment: @user770 "Find & Replace" some 100000 times? No thanks. I've tried some merging, but it's futile, leaving too many conflicts to resolve manually.

Comment: Is there a single commit in which the mass replace happened, or was the mass replace over multiple commits?

Comment: Is the replaced string the exact same length of the original string? I can't think of a good way to do this with *nix commands but I can write simple code to do this...

Comment: If the length is same this may be much more easier, can you confirm if the length of all `foo`, `bar` and `baz` is same?

Comment: @swalladge There were many commits, but I don't need to keep the history, so I can made them to one.

Comment: @TarunLalwani No, the length differs. And it were actually three whole words replacements like `perl -pe 's/\babc\b/pqrs/gi; s/\bdefg\b/uvw/gi; s/\bhi\b/xyz/g'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [`--word-diff=porcelain`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---word-diffltmodegt) mode of `git diff` (along with a sufficiently large value passed to the `-U` option, in order to preserve all the context between changes) and process its output with a simple enough script that will correct the wrong replacement.

> **`--word-diff[=<mode>]`** Show a word diff, using the `<mode>` to delimit changed words. By default, words are delimited by whitespace; 
>   see `--word-diff-regex` below. The `<mode>` defaults to `plain`, and
>   must be one of:
>
> - ...
> - **`porcelain`**: Use a special line-based format intended for script consumption. Added/removed/unchanged runs are printed in the usual
>     unified diff format, starting with a +/-/` ` character at the
>     beginning of the line and extending to the end of the line. Newlines
>     in the input are represented by a tilde `~` on a line of its own.

---

Below you will find a prototype `sed`-based implementation of the above approach.

**Usage**:

`fix_wrong_replacements` *`path`* *`revision`* *`replacement_fix`*

where

- *`path`* is the (relative) path of the file in the working tree
- *`revision`* is the revision since which the wrong replacements that must be fixed were made
- *`replacement_fix`* is a string of the form

  `/orig_pattern/incorrect_replacement_str/correct_replacement_str/`

**Effects**:

Assuming that the working copy of the file at *`path`* when compared
to its committed revision *`revision`* contains results of replacing
certain instances of *`orig_pattern`* with *`incorrect_replacement_str`*,
identifies those replacements and changes them to *`correct_replacement_str`*.

**Examples**:

```
# In last two commits (and, maybe, in the working copy) some "int"s
# were incorrectly changed to "unsigned", now change those to "long"
$myname main.c HEAD~2 /int/unsigned/long/

# In the working copy of somefile.txt all "abc" case-insensitive words
# were changed to "pqrs", now change them to "xyz"
$myname somefile.txt HEAD '/[aA][bB][cC]/pqrs/xyz/'
```

**Known limitations/issues**:

- It works for a single file. To fix all wrong replacements in a commit, commit range or local changes, must identify the list of changed files and call this script in a loop for all of them.
- If during the original (wrong) replacement case-insensitive mode was used, then the `orig_pattern` part of of the *`replacement_fix`* argument must use a `[aA]`, `[bB]`, etc, regex atom for each letter.
- Replacements immediately adjacent to other changes aren't handled.
- Sometimes a superfluous blank line may be added (because of a slight inconsistency in the output of `git diff --word-diff`)

**fix_wrong_replacements**:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

myname="$(basename "$0")"

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
    cat<<END
Usage:

    $myname <path> <revision> <replacement_fix>

where
    - <path> is the (relative) path of the file in the working tree
    - <revision> is the revision since which the wrong replacements that
      must be fixed were made
    - <replacement_fix> is a string of the form

        /orig_pattern/incorrect_replacement_str/correct_replacement_str/

Effects:

    Assuming that the working copy of the file at <path> when compared
    to its committed revision <revision> contains results of replacing
    certain instances of <orig_pattern> with <incorrect_replacement_str>,
    identifies those replacements and changes them to <correct_replacement_str>.


Examples:

    # In last two commits (and, maybe, in the working copy) some "int"s
    # were incorrectly changed to "unsigned", now change those to "long"
    $myname main.c HEAD~2 /int/unsigned/long/

    # In the working copy of somefile.txt all "abc" case-insensitive words
    # were changed to "pqrs", now change them to "xyz"
    $myname somefile.txt HEAD '/[aA][bB][cC]/pqrs/xyz/'
END
    exit 1
fi

file="$1"
revision="$2"
s=(${3//// })
orig_pattern="${s[0]}"
incorrect_replacement="${s[1]}"
correct_replacement="${s[2]}"

pat="-$orig_pattern\n+$incorrect_replacement"

git_word_diff()
{
    git diff -U100000                                       \
             --word-diff=porcelain                          \
             --word-diff-regex='[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*'    \
             "$@"
}


word_diff_file="$(mktemp)"
trap "rm $word_diff_file" EXIT

git_word_diff "$revision" -- "$file" > "$word_diff_file"
sed -n -e '
    1,5 d;

    /^-/ N;
    /\n~$/ d;
    /\n[- ]/ D;

    /^'"$pat"'$/ {x;G;s/\n'"$pat"'$/'"$correct_replacement"'/;x;d;};
    /^-.*\n+/ {s/^-.*\n+//;H;x;s/\n//;x;d;};

    /^~$/ {s/.*//;x;p;d;};

    {s/^.//;H;x;s/\n//;x;};
' "$word_diff_file" > "$file"
```

Answer (score -2):

To replace foo : grep -rl 'foo' . | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'

To replace bar : grep -rl 'bar' . | xargs sed -i 's/bar/baz/g'